# Create a Gensim model by specifying the word/topics distributions

Tags: gensim, lda, topic-modeling

I am doing some `topic modelling`work. If I understand things correctly, a `LDA` model is entirely defined by its word/topic distribution (which can be obtained with `model.get_topics()` in `gensim`. I am wondering if it is possible to create a `gensim` model by specifying this distribution, notably in order to use gensim's functions, such `CoherenceModel`, and topic prediction.

Comment: What do you mean by "create a gensim model"? Do you mean LdaModel?

Comment: Yes, for instance, though I don't know if there is a more generic class?